# Cant view some classes while inspecting APK's code

Tags: decompile, apk, jar

I'm trying to understand how the application works.
I used dex2jar utility to receive .jar file (`d2j-dex2jar --force file.apk`). And jd-gui to view it's classes.

I'm able to view the most of them. But the most IMPORTANT folder is shown to be empty. For some reason there is no .class file in that folder, though other classes do imports from it.

Did developers hide it. Or maybe there can be another reason?

What to try to get that file?

Comment: Why do you use dex2jar? This means decompiling the code two times, which means more chances to create errors. Better use a direct decompiler like jadx-gui or a different direct decompiler. Dex is very different to Java class files so this has to be considered as a decompilation as well.